# package Update failure

Tags: packages, miktex

I have installed MikTeX 2.9 in Windows. It does not allow to install new package, it fails...Even I tried to update(Admin)...It shows

> A connection Attempt failed....... A connection attempt failed because
> the connected party didnot properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond.
>
> Detail: connect failed in tcp_connect()".

Please help me.....

Comment: Well the connection failed. But you didn't give enough informations to decide why. You can try to change the repository in the package manager. But it could also be something on your pc/network that blocks the communication.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer, Thank you very much...I have already tried Repository option...and the reply is the same error message....Could you please tell me - how I can check my network problem...or what I do next to fix it?

Comment: Check for firewalls and proxies. I also know that vpn-tunnels can lead to time outs.

Comment: I've duped here to a slightly newer question where an answer has been given. As I say there, this is a network issue but beyond that we'd need more detail (and even then such things may well be off topic).